# addplot data frame

Tags: pgfplots, knitr

Square one: I have about 8 hours of experience. I want to make a barplot in `pgfplots` and see many great, creative solutions on this blog. All I want at this stage is not to specify coordinates and not to read in a `txt` file of some kind: I want to use a data frame created in R as my data set. I am not sure whether my question makes sense, perhaps too elementary.

The code below results in a very nice barplot.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar interval,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabel interval boundaries,
    x tick label style=
        {rotate=90,anchor=east}
    ]
\addplot coordinates
    {(0,2) (0.1,1) (0.3,0.5) (0.35,4) (0.5,3)
     (0.6,2) (0.7,1.5) (1,1.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

All I want is to use this data frame (data) in the code above

```
av<-c(3,4,5,6,7,8)
best<-c(11,14,15,16,21,9)
data<-rbind(av,best)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! How are you planning on getting the data frame from R to LaTeX? Are you using Sweave, or do you want to export the data frame to a text file?

Comment: I am using knitr.

Answer (score 2):

Are you tied to using `pgfplots` to produce the barplot?

The advantage of `knitr` is that you can just write the `R` code directly into the source document, and it will be evaluated as `R` code.

To do this, save your file as an `.Rnw` file, then compile it with `knitr` and then some (La)TeX engine. The [`knitr` website](http://yihui.name/knitr/) has some great tutorials on how to actually use `knitr` if you're just getting familiar with it. If you are just getting familiar with it, I would recommend using [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/) as your IDE because it provides an easy interface for using `knitr` in combination with LaTeX.

At any rate, you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE,include=TRUE>>=
av<-c(3,4,5,6,7,8)
best<-c(11,14,15,16,21,9)
data<-data.frame(av,best)

library(ggplot2)
y <- ggplot(aes(x=data$av,y=data$best),data=data, geom="bar", fill=factor(av)) + xlab("AV") + ylab("Best")
y + geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="mediumpurple1", colour="blue")
@

\end{document}
```

`<< >>=` begins the `R` code, and `@` ends the `R` code. The output is this:

[image]